# JavaScript: dynamic regex for my own parser

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying a new direction in Language Kits (or whatever you want to call those multi language text files with placeholders). Basically, I have text like this: `Hello, my name is %0. Welcome to %1!`. This would be my pText.

My pValues is an array whose values represent %0 and %1.

The following function should find %0 and replace it with pValues[0] and so on.

```
function _parseDialogMessage(pText, pValues) {
    var result = pText;
    for (var i=0; i<pValues.length; ++i) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\%'+i, 'gi');
        pText = pText.replace(regex, pValues[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It all works except for the fact that it does not replace the placeholders %0 and %1. All Variables have the expected values but .replace doesn't seem to find my placeholders.

Any help?

#### Edit 1

Shame on me... -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the `result` variable which hold the initial values of the `ptext` parameter..

return the `pText` variable..

Answer (score 4):

You don't need "dynamic regex", since `replace` can take a function as argument:

```
function _parseDialogMessage(pText, pValues) {
  return pText.replace(/%(\d+)/g, function (s, i) { return pValues[i]; });
}
```

(and you should `return pText`.)

Answer (score 0):

UUhm, you return result and not the replace pText

Answer (score 0):

While you can't use any of their code unless you want to GPL your library, the manual for gnu's gettext covers the rationale behind a number of topics related to internationalization.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html

edit : I know you're just looking for a magic regex, but it won't be enough.

easy example :

- I have %n computers.
- I have 1 computers.

Did you know arabic has a special tense for 2 things, and chinese no tense for the number of things referred to?